# Swagger UI does not display response models from custom annotation interface

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger

I am trying define global responses for swagger docs. I have the following annotation interface:

```
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiResponse;
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiResponses;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

import java.lang.annotation.*;

@Documented
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Inherited
@ApiResponses(value = {
        @ApiResponse(
                code = 200,
                message = "Successful status response"
        ),
        @ApiResponse(
                code = 401,
                message = "Unauthorized",
                response = Payload.Error.class
        ),
        @ApiResponse(
                code = 403,
                message = "Forbidden",
                response = Payload.Error.class
        ),
        @ApiResponse(
                code = 404,
                message = "Not Found",
                response = Payload.Error.class
        ),
        @ApiResponse(
                code = 500,
                message = "General Server Error",
                response = Payload.Error.class
        ),
})
@ResponseBody
public @interface PayloadResponse {
}
```

And inside the my controllers, I use this interface like this:

```
    @ApiOperation("Get user details after login")
    @PayloadResponse
    @GetMapping("/user")
    Payload<User> fetchUser(
            @ApiIgnore
            @RequestHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION) String authorization
    );
```

Here `Payload.Error` is an internal class of `Payload<T>`. But anyway, I tried with some other classes too, like: String, Map etc. but the swagger ui keeps displaying empty responses:

[image]

How can I manage to make it working from this point doing as little changes as possible?

Comment: Can you please explain how you are able to create a separate annotation `@ PayloadResponse ` and use `@ApiResponse` on it because when I do the same I am getting error. I have posted my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/71620927/7584240 Can you please provide some suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Springfox 3.0 uses v3 models by default but you are using `io.swagger.annotations.ApiResponses`  instead of `io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.responses.ApiResponses`
and `io.swagger.annotations.ApiResponse` instead of `io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.responses.ApiResponse`.
This problem has been documented at
https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/3503

But the workaround is also very easy. Just add a property to override v3 models with v2 models.

```
springfox.documentation.swagger.use-model-v3=false
```

And it works like a charm. Worked both with `@PayloadResponse` and as direct annotation at the endpoint.

I hope this is the one you wanted.
[image: Screenshot of swagger ui]

Comment: I am using springfox-swagger2 v3.0.0. ModelRef is deprecated in that version.

Comment: And this is not the answer I was looking for. I have 8 microservices in my app, and more may come later. I do not want to set global response message in swagger configuration of every services. I want to manage global response globally, preferably with something like annotations.

Comment: @Dipu I have updated the answer, hope this is the one you wanted.

Comment: Can you please explain how you are able to create a separate annotation `@ PayloadResponse ` and use `@ApiResponse` on it because when I do the same I am getting error. I have posted my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/71620927/7584240 Can you please provide some suggestion?