# Creating custom annotation with other annotation results into error '@APIResponses' not applicable to annotation type

Tags: java, annotations, swagger, openapi, quarkus

I have a Quarkus application to which I would like to add some `opernapi @APIResponses` annotations as there are many annotations on the `Quarkus service` class I wanted to create a separate `@Interface` and add the `@APIResponses` annotation on this interface and later use this `Interface` annotation on my `Quarkus service`.

When I create the new interface and add the `@APIResponses` then it would not work and I get the error: `'@APIResponses' not applicable to annotation type`. However if I directly use then I do not get any error.

Following is my Interface which is creating custom annotations:

```
import org.eclipse.microprofile.openapi.annotations.responses.APIResponse;
import org.eclipse.microprofile.openapi.annotations.responses.APIResponses;

import java.lang.annotation.*;

@Documented
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Inherited
@APIResponses(value = {
        @APIResponse(responseCode = "200", description = "Successful."),
        @APIResponse(responseCode = "404", description = "Invalid entries."),
        @APIResponse(responseCode = "401", description = "Missing ot invalid authorization information.")
})
public @interface PayloadResponse {
}
```

If I directly add the same `APIResponse` to my `Quarkus service` then I do NOT get any error, following is the code which is working currently:

```
import org.eclipse.microprofile.openapi.annotations.responses.APIResponse;
import org.eclipse.microprofile.openapi.annotations.responses.APIResponses;

@Path("/generate")
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@APIResponses(value = {
        @APIResponse(responseCode = "200", description = "Successful."),
        @APIResponse(responseCode = "404", description = "Invalid entries."),
        @APIResponse(responseCode = "401", description = "Missing ot invalid authorization information.")
})
public Multi<String> generate(final Map<String, Object> input) throws CustomException {
        
}
```

However I would like to replace the above code with something like this:

```
import org.eclipse.microprofile.openapi.annotations.responses.APIResponse;
import org.eclipse.microprofile.openapi.annotations.responses.APIResponses;

@Path("/generate")
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@PayloadResponse
public Multi<String> generate(final Map<String, Object> input) throws CustomException {
        
}
```

**Updated code based on example**

After looking at the following code example: [Swagger UI does not display response models from custom annotation interface](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64236324/7584240)
I tried to do something like that as well:

```
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.responses.ApiResponse;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.responses.ApiResponses;

import java.lang.annotation.*;

@Documented
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Inherited
@APIResponses(value = {
        @APIResponse(responseCode = "200", description = "Successful."),
        @APIResponse(responseCode = "404", description = "Invalid entries."),
        @APIResponse(responseCode = "401", description = "Missing ot invalid authorization information.")
})
public @interface PayloadResponse {
}
```

Also created the `application.properties` file:

```
springfox.documentation.swagger.use-model-v3=false
```

And added the `@PayloadResponse` to my method But still it's not showing up in my `swagger-ui`.

Also, I observe that in the example code they are using `code` within `ApiResponse` but when I check that annotation within my code it only accepts `responseCode` of String type and not code of Integer type as they have described.

Can someone please provide some explanation?

Comment: You cannot do that. APIResponses has the following: @Target({ElementType.METHOD}). It can only be applied to methods. More info here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/Target.html

Comment: @pringi Thanks for your response. But I found a question where they are doing this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/64236324/7584240 so I was trying to do something similar. Can you please have a look at that answer and provide some suggestion?

Comment: You are using org.eclipse.microprofile.openapi.annotations.responses.APIResponses. This annotation has as target a method. In the question that you refer they are using swagger (in package oas). And in ApiResponses in swagger you have a different target (method and annotation type)

Comment: @pringi Thanks for looking into the question. Yes, actually even I tried to add that dependency and make according to modification but still for some reason it does not seem to work for me. I have added the code same based on that example above in my question. Can you please have a look and provide some response?

Answer (score 0):

By default, the swagger defines a default set of response. To use your own response, you have to disable the default.

```java
@Configuration
public class SpringFoxConfig {

    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .paths(PathSelectors.ant("/api/**"))
                .build()
                .useDefaultResponseMessages(false);
    }

}
```

For openapi, you can use the properties to disable default option directly:

```
springdoc.override-with-generic-response=false
```